# using VS code to make UI to interact with smart contract

Tags: ethereum

I was following this tutorial on https://coursetro.com/courses/20/Developing-Ethereum-Smart-Contracts-for-Beginners. 
 testrpc is running and i don't know what else to do now.  below are the errors.

```
web3.min.js:1 Failed to load http://localhost:8545/: Response to preflight 
request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control- 
Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the 
request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'null' is therefore not 
allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the 
XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
t.send @ web3.min.js:1
web3.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node 
http://localhost:8545.
at Object.InvalidConnection (web3.min.js:1)
at t.send (web3.min.js:1)
at n.send (web3.min.js:1)
at l.accounts (web3.min.js:1)
at index.html:40
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this error by downgrading version of `web3` to `0.20.6` instead of 0.20.7. Anyone else has this problem, please try this solution.